# Which community is appropriate for a question about Microsoft's website?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I understand that

- for Apple questions, I should use the **Ask Different** community
- for Linux questions, I should use the **Unix & Linux** community

What about for questions about Microsoft services and products?  Given the extent of Microsoft's market share, I'm a bit surprised that there's not an obvious community dedicated to it.

The specific question I want to ask is:

> Microsoft Community, a.k.a. [answers.microsoft.com](https://answers.microsoft.com), is (or was) a
> community support forum (similar to discussions.apple.com).  It has
> been down for at least the last few days.  I have a bunch of bookmarks
> to pages on answers.microsoft.com, and they're all giving a "We are
> sorry... The page you requested is not available at this time" error.
> Maybe Microsoft has replaced it with some newer forum... but if you go
> to https://support.microsoft.com/en-us , it still contains an "Ask the
> community" link, which goes to answers.microsoft.com, which gives the
> aforementioned error.
>
> So my question is, has Microsoft replaced the Microsoft Community with
> something newer?  Or is this just a very extended outage, which seems
> rather unprecedented for a critical resource belonging to one of the
> world's largest companies?

Which Stack Exchange site would be the appropriate place to pose this question?

---

*Update:* Because the question is not related to programming, I went ahead and asked it in the **Super User** community.  Apparently that was the wrong community.  The question was closed for being off-topic.

Comment: Worth reading: https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7688/can-proposal-microsoft-be-closed (TL;DR: there was once a proposal for a site dedicated to Microsoft, which was closed.)

Comment: Yes, Laurel, I do have a specific question.  And it's not about Windows Phone, so I guess we're now down to three SE communities.  If you could please list those three communities, I can probably take it from there and decide which one is best suited for my question.

Comment: Well "questions about microsoft" is awfully broad. Narrow down your request in order to get meaningfull answers.

Comment: "The technical question that I will ask, if I eventually find out which Community is appropriate for Microsoft questions, doesn't seem appropriate for the Meta Community." It wouldn't be, no, but there's absolutely nothing wrong with asking, "I have a specific question XYZ, which SE site would it be most suitable for?"

Comment: @user3358338 If you have a question related to programming, you may ask it on [so] (C#, Visual Studio, among others, are products by Microsoft). If you have a question related to Windows or MS-Office, you may ask it on [su]. These are the two that I could think of off the top of my head. Of course, before posting on any child site, you should go through its Help Center and make sure that your (potential) question is on-topic.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange sites do I post on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-sites-do-i-post-on)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the example question is no longer reproducible.

Comment: @Luuklag In my opinion, it's still a valid example showcase question and asking where it fits is still a fine question. The scenario could be hypothetical or it could later happen again in the future.

Answer (score 3):

**I don't believe there is a site in the network that allows for this question.** It can only really be answered by Microsoft themselves. Any non-product-specific sister site handling computer-related questions (like the ones mentioned [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-sites-do-i-post-on)) on which questions about Microsoft services and products would be allowed, will still not answer questions about developer intent, nor would they be able to provide explanations for outages.

---

As for Super User not accepting it: their on-topic page explicitly [mentions](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) questions about "*websites or web services like Facebook, Twitter, and WordPress*" are off-topic.